# How to select a row based on the maximum value of a column, when ties are expected

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
SUBSCRIBER  DATE         TIME            VALUE
aaa         23-04-2015   04:04:07        10
aab         23-04-2015   12:04:32        5
bbb         23-04-2015   01:04:05        20
bbb         23-04-2015   12:04:20        20
bbb         23-04-2015   12:04:31        20
ccc         23-04-2015   05:04:00        10
```

I need a query to get the subscriber details based on the maximum `value` (and the minimum `time` if there are ties on `max(value)`) for a particular subscriber.

Comment: 1) what if there is a tie on the time, too? 2) Does this mean there is an additional table conatining subscriber details with (subscriber,time,value) as primary key? 3) It would be fine if you woul supply the table creation statements, sample data and sample output.  Then one can try it on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 3):

```
select subscriber, date_column, time_column, value from (
  select 
    subscriber, date_column, time_column, value,
    rank() over (partition by subscriber order by value desc, time_column) as r
  from mytab
) where r = 1
and subscriber = 'ccc';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select a.value
from your_table a
where a.value = (select max(value) from your_table)
and a.time = (select min(b.time) from your_table b where b.value = a.value)
```

That being said a description of the table would help.  Is Time a date time value or a string?

Answer (score -2):

The following should work as per your requirement. However, if there is a tie on the time too, it would pick a random row. You may want to choose a combination that would give you a unique row.

```
select myTable.* from myTable INNER JOIN 
    (select top 1 Value, Time
from myTable where subscriber = 'aaa'
order by Value desc, Time ) TT
ON myTable.Value = TT.Value
and myTable.time = TT.time
where subscriber = 'aaa'
```